# String Split only "UTC−11:00" from timeZones using regex java

Tags: java, javascript, regex, string, timezone

I want to split only "UTC−11:00" from time Zones using regex java.
My strings EX.

```
United States - UTC−12:00 : Baker Island and Howland Island
United States - UTC−11:00 : American Samoa, Jarvis Island, Kingman Reef, Midway Atoll and Palmyra Atoll
```

I want to work with this method. this method have to return only 'UTC-12:00'
Can u help here.

```
public native String jsRegExp(String str, String regex)
/*-{
  return str.replace(/regex/, '');  // an example replace using regexp 
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of picking the matched group using `Pattern`, you can use `replaceAll()` function of `String` class to replace it into your new shape!

```
String str = "United States - UTC-12:00 : Baker Island and Howland Island";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".*?-\\s+|(?<=\\d\\d:\\d\\d)\\s+:.*", ""));
```

In this example it is removing everything before the first `-` using `.*?-\\s+` and removing everything after the `xx:xx` using lookbehind checking (`(?<=\\d\\d:\\d\\d)\\s+:.*`)

**Update:** You are using `javascript` and its not `java`. Also, `Javascript` doesn't support `lookbehind`. You have to do it in a different way. For example:

```
var str = "United States - UTC-12:00 : Baker Island and Howland Island";
str = str.replace(/.*?-\s+|(\d\d:\d\d)\s+:.*/g, "$1");
```

Comment: getting error when parsing. Error is : 
    invalid quantifier

Comment: @npprasanth for which input or regex??

Comment: Exactly getting this while running application... columnNumber: 2: invalid quantifier.

but working in main method

Comment: @npprasanth please update your question with the code you are trying!

Comment: I have edited my question. By the way using regex in javascript i'm not getting exact value

Comment: @npprasanth I have updated my answer. Please check. You are using `javascript`. Its now similar to `java`.

Comment: but using this in eclipse shows '/d', '/s' are invalid escapse sequences. can u redefine this for me?